# java.lang.OutOfMemory Errors on Appo devices Running Android 5.1/5.1.1 only

Tags: android

I am encountering out of memory exception on android Appo devices. In particular these devices but only when running Android 5.1/5.1.1:

(A33w) Mirror 5 Lite
(F1f) F1
(1201) Joy 5

Looking at the spec they seem to have 1GB of memory.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to   throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available.  Don't have the device myself so just wondering what this might be. App has tons of downloads w/o this memory error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application manifest. `android:largeHeap="true"`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"  //<--- add this
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

If still facing problem, then it might be your bitmap scale is too large render. This mostly happens due to loading Large Image files which overflows assigned application memory by Android. It is mostly advised to load scale down versions into memory and re-use it from cache. visit https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html